# Differences between the Actor Model and Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP)

Tags: concurrency, message-passing

When we look at the [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and [Communicating Sequential Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) we see that they are both trying to do [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) based on [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), yet [they are distinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Contrast_with_other_models_of_message-passing_concurrency).

(We see implementations of the [CSP Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP#Overview) in [go-lang](http://golang.org/)'s [goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) (and [Clojure's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async)) and the Actor Model in [Scala's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) [Akka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_%28toolkit%29) toolkit)

I'm trying to get a simple list of the differences between the Actor Model and CSP. So far I have:

- actors message passing is asynchronous, CSP message passing is synchronous
- actors are [composable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Composing_Actor_Systems), CSP is not (necessarily)
- actors [always](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Unbounded_nondeterminism_controversy) have [unbounded non-determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_nondeterminism), CSP may have [bounded or unbounded non-determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Contrast_with_other_models_of_message-passing_concurrency)
- actors have [variable topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_creation_plus_addresses_in_messages_means_variable_topology) whereas CSP has fixed topology
- actors have the [principle of locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), CSP does not have locality
- actors are designed around their behaviour, CSP doesn't not necessarily have this

Is this correct? Is there anything I'm missing?

**Assumptions**

- When I say 'actor model' - I mean the theoretical basis behind the implementation in Scala's Akka framework

Comment: A huge point: In CSP message passing is synchronous; in Actors message passing is asynchronous.

Comment: @hawkeye What do you deem to be "the" actor model? Since its informal description, many formalisations have appeared, with somewhat different properties.

Comment: @Martin - that's helpful. I've updated my assumptions. Perhaps you can help me find the "one I'm looking for"

Comment: @hawkeye What to you mean by the Akka model? Only the key computational mechanism, or also the distributed monitoring/error-handling framework?

Comment: @MartinBerger just the key computational mechanism

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I think Erlang works. I believe Akka is very similar.

Each process has a single mailbox. Messages are put into the
receiver's mailbox by the sender, and fetched by the receiver using
pattern matching. This matching process can change message ordering in
the sense that the oldest message in a mailbox may not match, but a
younger one does. In this case the younger one is consumed
first. Other than that, message ordering is preserved.

With this in mind, the asynchronous $\pi$-calculus extended with input
pattern matching input from buffer describes Erlang (and hence Akka)
semantics accurately, although one needs to do a bit of work in the
encoding, since the $\pi$-calculus doesn't have the restriction to
single channels per process. However, one usually doesn't want an
encoding, but rather a calculus that models the target system
directly.  Such a calculus exists, and it's called [Featherweight
Erlang](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~dimitris/mostrous.vasconcelos.session-typing-erlang.pdf). It is by Mostrous and Vasconcelos. Their paper focusses on
typing, but you can ignore that and just look at the untyped calculus in Section 3.